Concerning Cartesian and Polar Function Graphs
First time poster so I apologize for any formatting mistakes.
If I had a function, say $f(x) = 2 \sin(2x)$, where $0\le x\le2\pi$ and graphed it on the Cartesian plane, then I took another function $r = 2 \sin(2\theta)$ and plotted that on a polar graph with a restricted domain of $0\le\theta\le2\pi$, it seems to me that no matter what the function is so long as the only difference between the two is that $x$ is swapped with $\theta$ and $r$ is swapped with $y$, that for any point on $f(x)$, $(x,y)$, there exists a point on the polar variant by which the value of $x$ and $y$ are interchanged to $\theta$ and $r$ respectively. For example, say on $f(x)$ there is a point $(2\pi,3)$, therefore on the polar graph there must be $(3,2\pi)$.
I've tried graphing many functions and found that this is seemingly true for all of them, and yet I can't seem to find a concise explanation or even anything articulating a similar idea. Either I'm poor at articulating the concept or I'm overanalyzing an inherent trait of the polar plane.
I found this Desmos graph on Reddit that seemingly visualizes the exact concept I'm describing. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ekhbcowmp4
If anyone could just make a bit more sense of the property for me or at least affirm that it is true it'd be much appreciated!

Cartesian coordinates give you a way of plotting pairs of numbers on a plane. Polar coordinates also give you a way of plotting pairs of numbers on a plane. Reversing the order of a pair so that, for example, $(2\pi,3)$ becomes $(3,2\pi)$, is also something you can do, or you can just change the rule for plotting a pair so that the first number is the angle and the second is the radius.
You can also identify each point in the plane with the position vector giving that point's direction and distance from the origin.
Then for a given coordinate system you have a function of two numeric parameters whose output is the position vector of the point at which that coordinate system would plot that pair of numbers.
Define $\operatorname{Cart}(v_1,v_2)$ as $v_1 \mathbf e_x + v_2 \mathbf e_y$ where
$\mathbf e_x$ and $\mathbf e_y$ are respectively the unit vectors in the direction of the $x$ and $y$ axes.
Then $\operatorname{Cart}(x,y)$ returns the position vector of the point with coordinates $(v_1,v_2)$ in the $x,y$ Cartesian coordinate system.
Define $\operatorname{Pol}(v_1,v_2)$ as $v_2 \mathbf e_{\theta}(v_1)$ where
$\mathbf e_{\theta}(v_1)$ is the unit vector in the direction $v_1$ radians counterclockwise from the positive $x$ axis.
Then $\operatorname{Pol}(\theta,r)$ returns the position vector of the point with coordinates $(r,\theta)$ (radius $r$, angle $\theta$) in the usual polar coordinate system.
For $0\leq k\leq 1$, the Desmos graph defines a vector function
$$
\operatorname{Polarify_1}(v_1,v_2,k) =
 (1-k) \operatorname{Cart}(v_1,v_2) + k \operatorname{Pol}(v_1,v_2)
$$
and a vector function
$$
\operatorname{Polarify_2}(v_1,v_2,k) =
 v_1 (1-k) \mathbf e_x + v_2 \mathbf e_{\theta}\left(kv_1 + \frac\pi2\right).
$$
(For $k > 1$ there is a different formula for $\operatorname{Polarify_2}(v_1,v_2,k)$, but let's just look at $0\leq k\leq 1$ for now.)
What $\operatorname{Polarify_1}$ does is conceptually very simple.
For $k=0$ it plots every pair of numbers $(v_1,v_2)$
according to $\operatorname{Cart}(v_1,v_2)$, that is, in Cartesian coordinates,
and for $k=1$ it plots $(v_1,v_2)$ according to $\operatorname{Pol}(v_1,v_2)$,
that is, in polar coordinates.
For $0 < k < 1$ it produces a linear combination of the two position vectors,
and since linear combination with coefficients $1-k$ and $k$ is a continuous function of the parameter $k$, as $k$ increases continuously from $0$ to $1$ we get a continuous deformation of the graph from Cartesian to polar coordinates.
The action of $\operatorname{Polarify_2}$ is a bit more complicated, but when $k=0$ it produces $v_1 \mathbf e_x + v_2 \mathbf e_y$
(because $\mathbf e_{\theta}\left(\frac\pi2\right) = \mathbf e_y$)
and for $k=1$ it produces $v_2 \mathbf e_{\theta}\left(v_1 + \frac\pi2\right)$,
which is almost what was wanted but is rotated $\frac\pi2$ radians from the desired orientation. The formula for $\operatorname{Polarify_2}(v_1,v_2,k)$ for $k > 1$ rotates the graph so that it arrives at the desired orientation when $k=2$.
Anyway, it's clear that if you hold $v_1$ and $v_2$ constant, the output of the vector function $\operatorname{Polarify_2}(v_1,v_2,k)$ changes continuously as $k$ changes continuously. Therefore you again get a continuous deformation from one coordinate system to the other as you vary $k$.
Another vector function you could consider is
$$
\operatorname{Polarify_3}(v_1,v_2,k) =
 v_1 (1-k) \mathbf e_x + v_2 \mathbf e_{\theta}\left(kv_1 + (1-k)\frac\pi2\right).
$$
Like $\operatorname{Polarify_2}$, this gives you Cartesian coordinates when $k=0$,
but when $k=1$ it produces $v_2 \mathbf e_{\theta}(v_1)$,
the same as $\operatorname{Pol}(v_1,v_2)$.
Again, the function is continuous with respect to $k$, so it continuously deforms the representation of a set of pairs of numbers from one coordinate system to the other.
This kind of thing works not just with Cartesian and polar coordinates but with any two coordinate systems that cover the plane.
Each coordinate system has a corresponding vector function that maps pairs of points to position vectors to plot those points in the plane, and you can construct a three-parameter vector function with a third parameter $k$ such that one value of $k$ plots points in one coordinate system, another value of $k$ plots them in the other coordinate system, and intermediate values of $k$ deform figures from one plot to the other plot.

You are looking at two different functions since they are realized in a different generating base for the space around them. The fact that their expressions match is entirely coincidental. To compare these two functions you should change the representation of one to match the other, and in that case you will see they have no relation whatsoever.
